# Expo 48L Unable to resolve AsyncStorage has been removed from react-native core

Tags: firebase, react-native, expo

I have been on this error for quite some time with no luck. The error was not solved after clearing caches, updating dependencies, and removing conflicting libraries that may be causing the error.

I have not used AsyncStorage anywhere explicitly in my project. This error has come after updating my project. Prior to the update, i was getting the yellow warning which was ignored for quite some time.

I have seen most answered refer to the change of the import. However, as mentioned there are not explicit use of the asyncstorage as an import anywhere.

Im not sure which part of my code needs to be shown. I'll include my package.json for now until further requests.

Thanks in advance

```
{
    "name": "my-project",
    "version": "1.0.0",
    "scripts": {
        "start": "expo start --dev-client",
        "android": "expo run:android",
        "ios": "expo run:ios",
        "web": "expo start --web",
        "eject": "expo eject"
    },
    "dependencies": {
        "@expo-google-fonts/raleway": "^0.2.2",
        "@freakycoder/react-native-bounceable": ">= 0.2.5",
        "@gorhom/bottom-sheet": "^4",
        "@react-native-async-storage/async-storage": "1.17.11",
        "@react-native-community/checkbox": "^0.5.12",
        "@react-navigation/native": "^6.0.10",
        "@react-navigation/native-stack": "^6.6.2",
        "@react-navigation/stack": "^6.2.1",
        "expo": "^48.0.0",
        "expo-app-loading": "~2.1.1",
        "expo-blur": "~12.2.2",
        "expo-haptics": "~12.2.1",
        "expo-location": "~15.1.1",
        "expo-splash-screen": "~0.18.2",
        "expo-status-bar": "~1.4.2",
        "firebase": "^8.2.3",
        "geolib": "^3.3.3",
        "lottie-react-native": "5.1.4",
        "react": "18.2.0",
        "react-dom": "18.2.0",
        "react-native": "0.71.8",
        "react-native-animatable": "^1.3.3",
        "react-native-floating-label-input": "^1.3.13",
        "react-native-gesture-handler": "~2.9.0",
        "react-native-google-places-autocomplete": "^2.4.1",
        "react-native-image-header-scroll-view": "^0.10.3",
        "react-native-keyboard-aware-scroll-view": "^0.9.5",
        "react-native-maps": "1.3.2",
        "react-native-nested-scroll-view": "^9.0.0",
        "react-native-reanimated": "~2.14.4",
        "react-native-safe-area-context": "4.5.0",
        "react-native-safe-area-view": "^1.1.1",
        "react-native-screens": "^3.20.0",
        "react-native-shared-element": "^0.8.4",
        "react-native-svg": "13.4.0",
        "react-native-swiper": "^1.6.0",
        "react-native-vector-icons": "^9.0.0",
        "react-native-web": "~0.18.7",
        "react-simple-form-validator": "^0.3.0",
        "valtio": "^1.2.11"
    },
    "devDependencies": {
        "@babel/core": "^7.19.3",
        "@types/react": "~18.0.24",
        "@types/react-native": "~0.70.6",
        "@types/react-native-vector-icons": "^6.4.10",
        "typescript": "^4.6.3"
    },
    "private": true
}
```